# Months after implementing JS redirects, hash bang URLs are still indexed in Google beside their replacements

Tags: seo, google, google-search, javascript, crawlable-ajax

We replaced our old site with a WordPress site around 6 months ago. Our old store plugin used links with AJAX fragments which were indexed in Google, like so:

```
https://www.example.com/store.php#!/item/info/etc
```

Fragments aren't exposed to the server so as I understand it our only option to redirect was to do a JS based redirect which I implemented many months ago. Based on my research (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39418767/2060441) I believed this would mean Google would update their indexes, however the old and new results both display in Google next to each other.

Is there a way to hurry it along? I have confirmed the new page that it redirects to is identified as the canonical page.